# How can i convert jquery to java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jquery function as js function how can i convert it?
my function is:--

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000
    })
});
```

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript ...

Comment: you rewrite the entirety of whatever `.carousel()` and `.ready()` are doing in pure JS. $() is easy enough: document.getElementById()

Answer (score 0):

write same code in JS on window.onload event using document.getElementByID